# Jquery, accessing data from a click within a function

Tags: jquery, jquery-click-event

I have this jquery code:

```
$('.viewmap').click(function () {

    updateMap();

});
```

So when someone clicks a link with the viewmap class it runs a function called updateMap. In the updateMap function I create a variable like so:

```
var mapid = $(this).attr('title');
```

The variable above does not work, it has a undefined value, my question is in the viewmap click function how do I access the current data via $(this) in the updateMap function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pass a reference of `this` to the updateMap function

```
$('.viewmap').click(function () {
    updateMap(this);
});

function updateMap(obj) {
    var mapid = $(obj).attr('title');
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

one alternative is to add a parameter to updateMap and call updateMap($(this)); instead of updateMap();

Answer (score 0):

There is two recomended ways:

```
    //If u don't want to do any work before the updateMap call
    $('.viewmap').click(updateMap);

    //If u want do do anything before updateMap call
    $('.viewmap').click(function(e) {
         updateMap.apply(this, arguments);
    });
```

Both ways will pass the this and every new argument jquery add now and in the future